# Discover where a list is referenced

Tags: sharepoint-online, list

I am using sharepoint 365.

The cliente need to delete one list.

He is not sure if any other list uses the list that will be deleted.

Is there a way to discover if the list is referenced into another areas of sharepoint?

Thank´s in advance

Comment: It might be complicated because the list my be referenced on different site collections, inside classic webparts, modern webparts, by search, Power Automate flows, Power Apps, by lookup fields, etc. Is it possible to narrow down the question/task? Otherwise, the quick answer - is no, we can't easity tell if the list is used. One very unreliable way would be to search this lsit by its name and URL and see what comes up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NO. AFAIK, there is no OOB way can achieve this requirement.